# Ampersand in array prevent looping through it

Tags: php, xml, arrays, foreach, ampersand

I'll be as descriptive as I can. I have an array that is generated by xml2array from an xml file that is coppied and pasted from a website that generates XML. I have no control over how the XML itself is formatted. The XML has duplicate fields, one is typeName one is entityTypeName. typeName corrects the ampersand and converts them to

```
&amp;
```

entityTypeName for some reason does not so the ampersands are left intact.

When trying to loop through the array, the array stops as soon as it gets to the first entityTypeName that contains an ampersand causing all other references after that to be "undefined."

If I manually change the ampersands in the XML file to

```
&amp;
```

then all is well but that is only feasible for debugging purposes.

I've even tried:

```
foreach ($entityArray as $key => $value) {
    $entityArray[$key]['entityTypeName'] = $entityArray[$key]['typeName'];
}
```

In an attempt to replace the faulty field with the one that works. It seems to replace it, but it still stops at the very spot where the ampersand is.

I've been asking in forums and I'm at a loss. Anyone with ideas?

**-- EDIT --**

I've been digging and the issue isn't the array itself but that it xml2array stops processing at the ampersand. Don't know if I should leave this question up or not now?

Comment: Answer your own question, that´s possible and it's clearer then an edit

Comment: There is no function `xml2array()` that is part of PHP itself, so you probably should first of all better specify what you do. Also this sounds quite like a bug-report. You normally don't need to convert XML into an array, it's often much more easy to just use `SimpleXMLElement` for a start.

Comment: It's been one of those things where I'm learning as I go so thanks for the clarification and steps in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't know SimpleXML yet, here are a set of basic usage examples: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic